# Removing contiguous spaces

Tags: string, vb.net

I only need to use Arrays and the Split() function, not the String.Spit().

This is what I have done so far, it keeps printing the same thing.

```
Function RemoveS(sta As String) As String
    Dim Warray() As String
    Dim sp As String = " "
    Dim EndStr As String = ""
    Warray = Split(sta, sp)
    For i = 0 To UBound(Warray)
        EndStr += Warray(i) + " "

    Next i

    Return EndStr
End Function
```

For example:

```
Dim A = "This is     a      wrong        String"


RemoveS(A)
```

Should output `"This is a wrong String"`

Comment: You know that strings are immutable, so you have to assign the returned string to a variable? So `RemoveS(A)` does not modify `A`, it returns a new string.

Comment: Why you don't want to use `String.Split`?

Comment: `If Warray(i) <> "" Then EndStr += Warray(i) + " "`.

Comment: My professor did not taught us this, he said to do the homework using only the things he taught us. I didn't quite get what you said, how should I assign the returned string to a variable? So I create another variable, let's say B and say B = RemoveS(A) ? Because I already tried that and still it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method which uses `Split()`, `Join()` and LINQ:

```
Dim wrongString As String = "This Is   a   wrong String"
Dim correctedString = RemoveContigousWhiteSpace(wrongString)


Function RemoveContigousWhiteSpace(str As String) As String
    Return String.Join(" ", Split(str, " ").
                       Where(Function(s) Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)))
End Function
```

You mentioned that you only can use Arrays and the `Split()`-function, so here's another approach with a `For`-loop:

```
Function RemoveContigousWhiteSpace(str As String) As String
    Dim strArr As String() = Split(str, " ")
    Dim corrString As String = ""

    For i As Integer = 0 To strArr.Length - 1
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(strArr(i)) Then
            If i = 0 Then
                corrString = strArr(i)
            Else
                corrString &= " " & strArr(i)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return corrString
End Function
```